# if a pandas column value is true, apply conditional statement to other column. The truth value of a Series is ambiguous error

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I have a column that returns True or False depending on a conditional statement ['gap pos']

depending on if that column is true or false I need another column to follow specific conditions in an IF ELIF statement. ['gap filled']

Here is the code:

```
mgn.loc[mgn['gap_size'] <= 0, 'gap pos'] = False
mgn.loc[mgn['gap_size'] >= 0, 'gap pos'] = True

if (mgn['gap pos'] == True):
    mgn.loc[mgn['Open2Close'] <= -1* (mgn['gap_size']), 'gap filled?'] = 'Filled'
    mgn.loc[mgn['Open2Close'] > -1* (mgn['gap_size']), 'gap filled?'] = 'Not filled'

elif (mgn['gap pos'] == False):
    mgn.loc[mgn['Open2Close'] >= abs(mgn['gap_size']), 'gap filled?'] = 'Filled'
    mgn.loc[mgn['Open2Close'] < abs(mgn['gap_size']), 'gap filled?'] = 'Not filled'
```

I do not want to put .any() after {if (mgn['gap pos'] == True)} because then my elif statement is not executed because my IF statement is satisfied. But if I dont put either .any(),.item(),.all() etc.

If i dont put  anything i receive:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I need my IF/ELIF statements to iterate over each row in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you try this instead of your if and elif conditions?
`mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] <= -1* (mgn['gap_size']))&(mgn['gap pos'] == True), 'gap filled?'] = 'Filled'`
`mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] > -1* (mgn['gap_size'])) & (mgn['gap pos'] == True) , 'gap filled?'] = 'Not filled'`
Do the same for elif condition. Bring the if condition inside with the `&` sign like i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring the if conditions inside for the if and elif conditions. Can you try this?

```
mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] <= -1* (mgn['gap_size'])) & (mgn['gap pos'] == True), 'gap filled?'] = 'Filled' 
mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] > -1* (mgn['gap_size'])) & (mgn['gap pos'] == True) , 'gap filled?'] = 'Not filled'

mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] >= abs(mgn['gap_size'])) & (mgn['gap pos'] == False), 'gap filled?'] = 'Filled'
mgn.loc[(mgn['Open2Close'] < abs(mgn['gap_size'])) & (mgn['gap pos'] == False), 'gap filled?'] = 'Not filled'
```

Comment: This worked thank you! It looks like pandas needs the & or | whenever possible. Thanks for your effort and help.